# Change color based on a difference of value from previous value to current value SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to compare the current row value to the previous row value but only within the same group.

I have Group1 (Plant), ChildGroup1 (DeviceTag), Details Group,
I have tried this code within the Fill property but it does not work, it just seems to change the color of the first row every time per group regardless of the value of the previous row.

```
=IIf(Fields!DeviceTag.Value <> Previous(Fields!DeviceTag.Value), "Yellow", "White")
```

So my data set looks like this:

```
Plant       DeviceTag       Description    Location

  A            Tag1            ABCD          West
               Tag1            WXYZ          West      DeviceTag Group 1
_____________________________________________
  A            Tag2            EFGH          East
               Tag2            IJKL          East      DeviceTag Group 2
               Tag2            IJKL          West
```

In both these DeviceTag Groups, the description changed so I would like to change the color of ABCD to yellow and EFGH to yellow but not WXYZ because it is not in the same group as EFGH.  Also the Second row that says East should be Yellow since it is different than the previous West location.

In Crystal Reports you would do:

```
if {#ChangeCounter}=1 then nocolor else
if currentfieldvalue <> previous({DataSet.Field}) then cryellow else nocolor
```

Where the formula #ChangeCounter is just 1

Clear as mud??

Comment: `=IIF(RUNNINGVALUE(Fields!Description.Value, COUNTDISTINCT,"DataSetName") MOD 2 = 0, 
       "Yellow", 
        "White")` Not sure if this is what you are after..... change dataset name accordingly

Comment: Where does the "DataSetName" come from, where is that designated?  Is that the Tablix name?

Comment: wherever you are building your report, you should have some Report Data, this will have a datasource folder and a dataset folder. The name of your dataset will be in there. Usually defaulted to DataSet1

Comment: Mine was default DataSet1, however, this seems to randomly color the values, sometimes for a change, sometimes when there is no change.  Does not seem to have anything to do with the groups either.

Comment: try `=IIf(Fields!DeviceTag.Value = Previous(Fields!DeviceTag.Value), Nothing, "Yellow")`

Comment: That does the exact same thing as my original Expression.  It fills the first row cell of each Group for that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find this kind of thing easier to do in the dataset query (assuming you can control the query in the dataset).

Manipulate your final dataset (the one SSRS will receive) to have another column which tells SSRS to color the cell or not. And keep your business logic in the DB query.

You could number each row (within each group) using `row_number()` and then join the table back into itself on the new row number column.

Something like this perhaps? I am not sure I 100% follow your cell shading logic and I am sure your dataset is larger than what you provided, but you may be able to adapt this to meet your needs.

```
;with Data as 
(
    select 'A' as Plant, 'Tag1' as DeviceTag, 'ABCD' as Description, 'West' as Location union all
    select 'A' as Plant, 'Tag1' as DeviceTag, 'WXYZ' as Description, 'West' as Location union all
    select 'A' as Plant, 'Tag2' as DeviceTag, 'EFGH' as Description, 'East' as Location union all
    select 'A' as Plant, 'Tag2' as DeviceTag, 'IJKL' as Description, 'East' as Location union all
    select 'A' as Plant, 'Tag2' as DeviceTag, 'IJKL' as Description, 'West' as Location
),

DataWithRowNumbers as
(
select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by DeviceTag order by Description) as DeviceTagGroupRowNumber
from
    Data    
)

select
    a.*,
    case when a.Description != b.Description then 'Yellow' else 'Transparent' end as CellColor
from
    DataWithRowNumbers a
    left join DataWithRowNumbers b on a.DeviceTag = b.DeviceTag and a.DeviceTagGroupRowNumber = b.DeviceTagGroupRowNumber - 1
```

Then you can set the background in the cell (in SSRS) to an expression which will just be `Fields!CellColor.Value`.

Comment: I have complete control over the query in the dataset.  Can you give me an example of how I would add a column to SSRS to color the cell?

Comment: updated the answer with an example - not 100% sure of your business logic

Comment: This basically concatenates the whole row of columns and then does a compare of the whole previous row (if I'm looking at the results correctly).  What I really need is to compare the rows like your doing but only turn the columns that have changed to yellow.

Comment: I think you will need multiple `CellColor` columns then - one for each field you wish to apply the business logic to.

Comment: So your saying just add multiple case statements:  `case when a.CyberAssetDesc != b.CyberAssetDesc then 'Yellow' else 'Transparent' end as CyberAssetDescCellColor,
 case when a.DeviceLoc != b.DeviceLoc then 'Yellow' else 'Transparent' end as DeviceLocCellColor`

Comment: Yes. Then in SSRS when you set the background color for the cell, just choose the correct field based on the cell/column you are on.

Comment: How do I do this with a select query for the dataset instead of using the `with Data as` section, SSRS  still needs a query from a table although this code does work directly in SQL when running `;with Data as 
(  
    select * from [dbo].[table_tbl]
),

DataWithRowNumbers as
( `

Comment: Whatever your query is, you can just stick in inside of the `;with Data (<insert query here>)` section. I used CTEs (common table expressions) for the example. The results of any select query really can be shoved into a CTE. You dataset in SSRS will work with CTEs, I do it daily.

Comment: Don’t use the query designer. Can you paste it directly into the query window of the dataset (the big text box). Complex queries never show up correctly in the query designer/builder.

Comment: Yup, it is all working now, thanks, i will reward your well earned points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Scope parameter of the Previous function, providing the name of your ChildGroup1 (DeviceTag).  e.g.

=IIf(Fields!DeviceTag.Value <> Previous(Fields!DeviceTag.Value , "ChildGroup1" ), "Yellow", "White")

Here's the doco:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-previous-function

Comment: That syntax does not seem correct, it underlines Previous(Fields!DeviceTag.Value , "DeviceTag")      When I apply it, it colors all DeviceTag entries Yellow.

Comment: Unfortunately the syntax checking often lags changes in the syntax. Note the 2nd parameter should be the Row Group Name, not the Field Name.